# C# XML RPC = Response not valid XML RPC - Using CookComputing XMLRpc.net

Tags: c#, wordpress, xml-rpc

I develop an open source project called JoeBlogs - it's a C# wrapper for Wordpress, and other blogs.

Here's a post on using JoeBlogs
http://www.alexjamesbrown.com/geek/using-joeblogs/

Recently, i've had a lot of comments that people are getting an error on the CookComputing component:
“Response XML not valid XML-RPC – missing methodResponse element"

I think it's with the latest version of Wordpress-
I've tried using fiddler to see the response, however can't seem to make it out any more.

Since this project is open source, i thought i'd ask and see if anyone had any ideas here?
It's hosted on CodePlex - http://joeblogs.codeplex.com

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this:

http://www.alexjamesbrown.com/geek/development/dotnet/joeblogs-typo-in-dummy-url-fixed/